# Is it okay to prove this by contradiction?

Tags: proof-writing, alternative-proof

I am learning how to prove and I would like to know whether it is right to prove by this method or if it could prove in any better way.

> There is no pair of integers $ a $ and $ b $ for which $ 14a + 2014b =
>  1$

Assume that the pair exists and from there find the contradiction.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, proving it by contradiction is fine. Is that really the question you are intending to ask here?

Comment: Assuming that the pair exists, do I simply solve for one of the variables?

Answer (score 2):

**Not sure if it's perfectly correct but here's what I think**

a=(1-2014b)/14
Now as a is an integer so is the b, 
(1-2014b) should be divisible by 14 i.e. 
Div. By 2 as well.
But as 2014b is even (1-2014b) can never be div. By 2 as it's odd. And hence no soln exist , you can also check other way around.
*hope it helps pardon otherwise*

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $14a+2014b=2(7a+1007b)$ Can you go from here?

Comment: Would this be part of the proof by contradiction?

Comment: If $a,b$ are integers then $14a+2014b=1$ has no solutions is an equivalent statement of the problem. using my hint you can prove this directly or by contradiction.